# How do I add modules to my Skulpt page?

Tags: javascript, python, module, skulpt

I want `NumPy` to be available on my `Skulpt` site that I am making.

How do I implement it?

I get an error when using the following code

```
Sk.externalLibraries = {
        numpy : {
              path: 'https://github.com/waywaaard/skulpt_numpy'
        }
};
```

Here's the error

> **ImportError**: Invalid file extension specified for numpy on line 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the actual script you want to import when you `import numpy` probably like this:

```
Sk.externalLibraries = {
    numpy : {
          path: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/waywaaard/skulpt_numpy/master/numpy/__init__.js'
    },
    'numpy.random': {
         path: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/waywaaard/skulpt_numpy/master/numpy/random/__init__.js'
    }
};
```